# Upgrade Android OS without SIM card

Tags: ota-update, sim-card

I have a Moto E phone which I bought from Tesco in the UK. I assume it is unlocked as it doesn't have any Tesco mobile branding on it when I turn it on.

I have already tried the manual way and it says it's up to date. But I know that a Lollipop update is coming soon, so I'm not sure whether it is available and I need a SIM to download over WiFi.

Can I upgrade it to Lollipop without the SIM card?

Answer (score 1):

No. You won't need a SIM card. Simply connecting to a working WiFi network is all you need to check and update your Moto E. Here is a [post from an user](http://forums.androidcentral.com/ask-question/461815-can-i-get-lollipop-update-nexus-5-no-sim-card.html#post4054515) on Androidcentral claiming he updated without a SIM card.

You might want to read : [Who are responsible for pushing out the OTA updates?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/25603/who-are-responsible-for-pushing-out-the-ota-updates)

Comment: I was under the assumption that only Nexus devices or those brought directly from Google getthe update directly from Google.

Comment: @Vic One of my friend who has Moto phone updated it via Wifi network without a SIM card..You wont directly get it from google but the manufacturer/carrier will tweak the OS for the corresponding phone and sent it Over The Air(OTA)..it depend on the carrier and region etc.